# How to plot yesterdays 30min Timeframe Low on todays chart

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

want to plot yesterdays first candle's low of a 30min time frame on todays chart no matter what time frame todays chart is .

could anyone help me out with this?

`````````````````````````
newDay   = dayofweek != dayofweek[1]                                                   
dayOpen  = 0.0, dayOpen  := newDay ? open      : nz(dayOpen[1])                        
dayHigh  = 0.0, dayHigh  := newDay ? high      : nz(dayHigh[1])  
prvHigh  = 0.0, prvHigh  := newDay ? dayHigh[1]  : nz(prvHigh[1])  
dayLow   = 0.0, dayLow   := newDay ? low       : nz(dayLow[1])                         
prvLow   = 0.0, prvLow   := newDay ? dayLow[1] : nz(prvLow[1])                         
dayClose = 0.0, dayClose := newDay ? close     : nz(dayClose[1]) 
prvClose = 0.0, prvClose := newDay ? dayClose[1] : nz(prvClose[1])
dayHL2   = 0.0, dayHL2   := newDay ? hl2       : nz(dayHL2[1])                         
````````````````````````
`````````````````````````

Comment: This can only be done on a 30min timeframe or lower timeframe, because you can't access lower timeframe data in pine. Only higher timeframe data.

Comment: yeah todays chart will be 5min .. is there any possibility like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will plot that value. When a new day comes in and it has not yet found the low for the first 30min TF, it will not plot a value. It will ofc only work when your chart's TF <= 30min:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
i_tf = input("30", type = input.resolution)
newTf = change(time(i_tf))
newDay = change(time("D"))
var float prevLo = na
var float lo = na
if newDay
    prevLo := lo
    lo := low
else if newTf and not na(lo)
    prevLo := lo
    lo := na
else
    lo := min(lo, low)

plot(prevLo, "prevLo", color.orange, 1, plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Its only plotting today low @PineCoders-LucF not yesterdays